# QGIS2Leaf fails with AttributeError: 'QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2' object has no attribute 'penStyle'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis2leaf

Can anyone tell me what this means? and what I have to do to get it done?

I'd like to export my map from QGIS to use as a webmap. Data is from a postGIS database.

> Fehler bei der Ausführung von Python-Code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/kevin_hh/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgis2leaf/qgis2leafdialog.py",
>   line 297, in export2leaf
>       qgis2leaf_exec(self.outFileName, self.basemapName, self.basemapMeta, self.basemapAddress, self.width, self.height,
>   self.extent, self.full_screen, self.layer_list, self.visible,
>   self.opacity, self.encode2JSON,self.createcluster, self.webpage_name,
>   self.webmap_head,self.webmap_subhead,
>   self.legend,self.locate,self.address, self.precision, self.labels,
>   self.labelshover, self.matchCRS, self.selected)   File
>   "/Users/kevin_hh/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgis2leaf/qgis2leaf_exec.py",
>   line 575, in qgis2leaf_exec
>       opacity: '""" + str(symbol.alpha()) + """', AttributeError: 'QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2' object has no attribute 'penStyle'
>
> Python-Version:
>   2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
>
> QGIS-Version:
>   2.8.3-Wien Wien,
>
> Python-Pfad:
>   ['/Applications/QGIS_Wien.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing',
>   '/Applications/QGIS_Wien.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python',
>   u'/Users/kevin_hh/.qgis2/python',
>   u'/Users/kevin_hh/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   '/Applications/QGIS_Wien.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7/site-packages',
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override',
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override',
>   '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
>   u'/Users/kevin_hh/.qgis2//python',
>   '/Users/kevin_hh/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   '/Applications/QGIS_Wien.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools',
>   '/Users/kevin_hh/Desktop/Projekt slowUp Basel-Dreiland']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qgis2leaf does not support Marker line styles. Also, qgis2leaf is no longer being developed. Its functionality has been included in qgis2web, but I believe qgis2web also does not support Marker line styles. Do try, and report an issue on Github if it fails.

UPDATE: qgis2web does not crash with Marker line styles. However, the Marker line style is not reproduced - it fails over to a plain polygon style.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works more or less with qgis2web!